# tab bootstrap - open external link

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hello I have this scenario,

```
<ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li class=""><a href="#Tab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">TAB1</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#archiviobando" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab2</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.google.it" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab3</a></li>
</ul>
```

I would to use the tab feature of bootstrap only for the first two link...with the last link I need to open with a normal URL...How can I do?

I have insert the classic JS code  for activate the TAB

```
$('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault()
     $(this).tab('show')
})
```

But when I click on the last tab...I see this error:

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: http://www.google.it
ed?a.value:null:a},at.error=function(e){throw Error("Syntax error, unrecognized ...
```

**SOLVE TNX A @LIX**
I have change with this code the JS function and now work!:

```
$('#myTab a[data-toggle]').click(function
```

Tnx to all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you may want to simply remove the `data-toggle="tab"` attribute of the `a` element but if you want to use some codings you can attain that with this simple logic

```
$("#myTab li").last().on('click', function() {
   window.location.href = 'http://www.google.it';
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7579to11/)

Comment: Why re-implement the functionality of an anchor tag?

Answer (score 1):

You could remove the `data-toggle="tab"` attribute from the tab as it's hooked up using live/delegate events

CODE:

```
<ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li class=""><a href="#Tab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">TAB1</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#archiviobando" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab2</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.google.it" role="tab">Tab3</a></li>
</ul>
```

[Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakmanwal/K9LpL/755/)

When I commented jQuery code:

```
/*$('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault()
     $(this).tab('show')
})*/
```

Then error is gone:

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: http://www.google.it ed?a.value:null:a},at.error=function(e){throw Error("Syntax error, unrecognized ..

[DEMO With ERROR](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakmanwal/e1k7j6qo/)

Comment: Have you tested this?

Comment: Yes @Lix i have tested it

Comment: Ahh - yes - sorry. I was testing it on an older version of bootstrap (2.3.2). With the current version it does work :)

Comment: I have updated my question...when I click on the last tab ...generate an error JS

Comment: @DanieleGrillo - please add details of this error to your question. Saying "there is an error" is of no use to anyone if you don't share what the error was.

Comment: @Lix When I click on Tab3 Firebug show this error: **Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: http://www.google.it
...ed?a.value:null:a},at.error=function(e){throw Error("Syntax error, unrecognized ...***

Comment: @DanieleGrillo - in your original post please - not in the comments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59635/discussion-between-daniele-grillo-and-lix).

Comment: @Manwal Tnx a lot, I have used the solution from Lix user, I have update my post with the final solution. Tnx verty much to all